# Why doesn't this process end?

Tags: scripting, find, uniq

```
 wc -l | sort -t":" -k4,4n | uniq password_demo.txt
```

prints

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/usr/sbin/nologin
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/usr/sbin/nologin
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/usr/sbin/nologin
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/usr/sbin/nologin
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/usr/sbin/nologin
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/usr/sbin/nologin
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/usr/sbin/nologin
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/nologin
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/usr/sbin/nologin
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/usr/sbin/nologin
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/usr/sbin/nologin
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/usr/sbin/nologin
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/usr/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
systemd-timesync:x:100:102:systemd Time Synchronization,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
systemd-network:x:101:103:systemd Network Management,,,:/run/systemd/netif:/bin/false
systemd-resolve:x:102:104:systemd Resolver,,,:/run/systemd/resolve:/bin/false
systemd-bus-proxy:x:103:105:systemd Bus Proxy,,,:/run/systemd:/bin/false
syslog:x:104:108::/home/syslog:/bin/false
_apt:x:105:65534::/nonexistent:/bin/false
messagebus:x:106:110::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
uuidd:x:107:111::/run/uuidd:/bin/false
lightdm:x:108:114:Light Display Manager:/var/lib/lightdm:/bin/false
whoopsie:x:109:117::/nonexistent:/bin/false
avahi-autoipd:x:110:119:Avahi autoip daemon,,,:/var/lib/avahi-autoipd:/bin/false
avahi:x:111:120:Avahi mDNS daemon,,,:/var/run/avahi-daemon:/bin/false
colord:x:112:123:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:113:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
hplip:x:114:7:HPLIP system user,,,:/var/run/hplip:/bin/false
kernoops:x:115:65534:Kernel Oops Tracking Daemon,,,:/:/bin/false
pulse:x:116:124:PulseAudio daemon,,,:/var/run/pulse:/bin/false
rtkit:x:117:126:RealtimeKit,,,:/proc:/bin/false
saned:x:118:127::/var/lib/saned:/bin/false
usbmux:x:119:46:usbmux daemon,,,:/var/lib/usbmux:/bin/false
speech-dispatcher:x:120:29:Speech Dispatcher,,,:/var/run/speech-dispatcher:/bin/false
user:x:1000:1000:user,,,:/home/user:/bin/bash
sshd:x:121:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

which is correct, but the process never finishes. I have to ctrl+c to get out of it. What am i missing from the command line?

I asked a question earlier, but it turns out this bug is the reason my earlier question is wrong so I'm doubly in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

All parts of a pipeline are started pretty much simultaneously. It is only input/output that synchronises the different stages of a pipeline.

In your pipeline,

```
wc -l | sort -t":" -k4,4n | uniq password_demo.txt
```

`uniq` will get its input from the given file, while `wc -l` will be waiting for input from its standard input (whatever you type at the terminal in this case), and `sort` will be waiting for input from `wc`.  The output from `sort`, if it gets any input, will be discarded since the `uniq` process won't be reading it.

---

To count how many unique lines there are in your file:

```
sort -u password_demo.txt | wc -l
```

The `-t` and `-k` flags are not needed since we're interested in whole lines.  The `-u` flag makes `sort` only output unique lines.

If you're interested in counting how many unique values of the fourth `:`-separated field there are, you will have to extract these and sort them:

```
awk -F ':' '{ print $4 }' password_demo.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

Alternatively:

```
cut -d ':' -f 4 password_demo.txt | sort -u | wc -l
```

See the manuals for `cut` and `awk` on your system for more information about these commands.

Comment: I don't know what OP is doing with the `-t`/`-k`, but it could be they just want at most one user from a group (so eliminating one of sshd/nobody?)... not sure, though.

Comment: @Olorin It's definitely not clear from the question. I was just giving an example of something they may want to do based on the text that they provided.

Answer (score 1):

In `wc -l | sort -t":" -k4,4n | uniq password_demo.txt`, `uniq` is reading from the file (and ignoring the pipe). `wc` is waiting for input (from stdin, the terminal), since it was not given a filename to read from, and so `sort` is also waiting for input (`wc`'s output). You could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to signify end of input from terminal and `wc` will exit.

Did you mean `sort -t":" -k4,4n password_demo.txt | uniq`? Or `sort -t":" -k4,4n -u password_demo.txt`? I don't see how `wc -l` fits in here.

Comment: I need uniq and sort to filter out non unique entries, then wc to count how many lines are leftover

Comment: `sort -t":" -k4,4n password_demo.txt | uniq -c` would be enough for that, without needing `wc`.

Comment: You are right, i needed to move password_demo.txt to the sort side.

Comment: Ah, sorry you will need `wc`. `uniq -c` does something else, sorry. So: `sort -t":" -k4,4n -u password_demo.txt | wc -l`, since `sort` can filter unique entries.